# Kivy - Schedule Something for the future

Tags: python, time, kivy

I'm trying to write an app that you can input tasks. When you input these tasks, you give a time too, for example 10:30 AM. When that time comes, you get alerted of the task. I figured out the alerting part, but I just don't know how to call a function at some point in the future without interrupting the rest of the code while its running. Kivy's built in clock function seems to small scale for something like this.

What I tried to do that interrupted the rest of the code:

```
  def submit_button(self):
        #account id and auth token omitted 
        account_id = ""
        auth_token = ""
        client = Client(account_id, auth_token)
        self.name_in_q = self.ids.the_name.text
        self.time = f'{self.ids.time_spinner_1.text}:{self.ids.time_spinner_2.text} {self.ids.time_spinner_3.text}'
        waiting_for_task = True
        while waiting_for_task:
            tz_hous = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
            datetime_houston = datetime.now(tz_hous)
            ds = datetime_houston.strftime("%H:%M")
            t = time.strptime(ds, "%H:%M")
            ds = time.strftime("%I:%M %p", t)
            if(ds == self.time):
                client.messages.create(
                    body = f"Complete your task: {self.name_in_q} for {self.time}",
                    # phone numbers omitted 
                    from_ = "+",
                    to = "+"
                )
                break
```

Comment: Kivy has class [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) for this. Don't use `while` loops in any GUI because it will block all code.

Comment: i don't know why you use `time` if you can use directly `datetime.now(tz_hous).strftime("%I:%M %p")`